# Call to member function on non-object, but object is $this i.e. itself?

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I have a simple extension to PDO and PDOStatement classes for error logging if a query happens to go wrong. Here is my code simplified:

```
class MyPDO extends PDO
{
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        try
        {
            parent::__construct('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $db, $user, $pass);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('MyPDOStatement', array($this)));
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            $this->error(array($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), '08006'));
        }
    }

    function query($query)
    {
        $stmt = parent::query($query);
        if ($stmt !== false)
            return $stmt;
        else
        {
            $this->error($this->errorInfo(), $query);
            return false;
        }
    }

    function error($info, $query = false)
    {
        // log error here
    }
}
```

Obviously, I have overwritten the prepare() and exec() methods, and the execute() method of the statement class as well. When those (or query() as above) have an error, they all work fine. The problem is when PDO fails to connect to the database, I get the "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function error() on a non-object" error on the line contained in the catch.

I've tried replacing it with MyPDO::error() for the catch, but that just seems to not do anything on error. I'm stumped on what the problem is.

Comment: Looks odd. It might be interesting to see what `parent::__construct` does

Comment: @Pekka it tries to create a PDO instance but probably fails horribly because there is no $user and $pass available.

Comment: @Gordon true :) but I was rather about what else it does to `$this` to cause this. Do you have an explanation? I can't think of one. Can `$this` be unset in a constructor?

Comment: I cut out setting of variables (including the setting of $user and $pass). They aren't important because it's the case of it failing that I am having problems with. I do not unset anything or call any other functions though. The parent constructor throws the exception, but it shouldn't stop references within my class from working?

Comment: a wrapper around a wrapper around an api - hmmmm nice indirection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug in PDO. The following prints "NULL" and not "object(MyPDO)" as expected.

```
class MyPDO extends PDO
{
    public function __construct() {
        try {
            parent::__construct(111);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            var_dump($this);
        }
    }
}

$p = new MyPDO;
```

PDO::construct seems to throw an exception before the object is completely initialized.

They say it's already fixed, http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52053, so try upgrading to the most recent version.

Comment: Well, it's nice to know I wasn't just crazy assuming this should work as a previous commenter suggested against on your answer (who later deleted it). I'm currently on php 5.3.3 and I don't see this bug listed in the changelog for 5.3.4. Maybe they haven't yet put that fix into the public release. Anyways, thanks for the answer, I'll work around the problem by using a function not contained in the class.